# Turning isolated Scope in anuglar js on and off?

Tags: angularjs

> Question: Below is the code that I am using angular database js with modal popup and for some reason the modal popup works on and off.
>   I tried setting scope options and nothing seems to work. Another wired
>   thing is when I load developer tools in chrome and debug it will start
>   working. Upon subsequent refresh it will not.  Can some one help me
>   out?

```
    <head>

        <title>System Check Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('showcase.angularWay.withOptions', ['datatables', 'ngResource']);
            app.controller('AngularWayWithOptionsCtrl', function ($resource, $scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.clients = [];
                vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(10);
                vm.dtColumnDefs = [
                    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
                    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4).notSortable(),
                    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notSortable(),
                    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6).notSortable()
                ];
                $resource('SystemCheck/GetClientConfigDetails').query().$promise.then(function (clients) {
                    vm.clients = clients;
                });

                $scope.showModal = false;
                $scope.toggleModal = function () {
                    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
                };
                $scope.EtimeDBUP = function (response) {
                    $http.get('SystemCheck/GetEtimeDbStatus/' + response.Coid).then(function (etimeResponse) {

                        $scope.EtimeDBResponse = "For " + response.CustomerId + ":" + etimeResponse.data.processMessages[0].userMessage.codeValue;
                        if (etimeResponse.data.processMessages[0].userMessage.messageTxt == "200") {
                            $scope.class = "btn-success";
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.class = "btn-danger";
                        }
                        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
                    });

                };
                $scope.EtimeXMLUP = function (response) {
                    $http.get('SystemCheck/GetEtimeXMLStatus/' + response.Coid).then(function (etimeResponse) {

                        $scope.EtimeDBResponse = "For " + response.CustomerId + ":" + etimeResponse.data.processMessages[0].userMessage.codeValue; $scope.EtimeDBResponse = "for " + response.Coid + ":" + etimeResponse.data.processMessages[0].userMessage.codeValue;
                        if (etimeResponse.data.processMessages[0].userMessage.messageTxt == "200") {
                            $scope.class = "btn-success";
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.class = "btn-danger";

                        }
                        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
                    });

                };

            });
            app.directive('modal', function () {
                return {
                    template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
                        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                          '<div class="modal-content">' +
                            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                              '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
                          '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>',
                    restrict: 'E',
                    transclude: true,
                    replace: true,
                    scope: true,
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.title = attrs.title;
                        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function (value) {
                           if (value == true) {
                                $(element).modal('show');
                            }

                            else {
                                $(element).modal('hide');
                            }

                        });
                        $(element).on("close", function () {
                            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                        });
                        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                            });
                        });

                        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                            });
                        });


                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="showcase.angularWay.withOptions">
        <div ng-controller="AngularWayWithOptionsCtrl as showCase">
            <h1 style="font-weight: bolder; font-style: oblique; font-family: sans-serif; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 4px">Mobile System Check</h1>
            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="showCase.dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: left">COID</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">CUSTID</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">ETIMEML</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">PAYROLLPRODUCT</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">ETIMEDBUP</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">ETIMEXML</th>
                        <th style="text-align: left">INSTANCE RESTART</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="client in showCase.clients">
                        <td>{{client.Coid}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.CustomerId}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.EtimeUrl}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.PayRollProduct}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="EtimeDBUP(client)">EtimeDBUP</button></td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="EtimeXMLUP(client)">ETIMEXMLUP</button></td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning">INSTANCE RESTART</button></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
            <modal title="Result" visible="showModal">
                   <div ng-class="class" class="well">{{EtimeDBResponse}}</div>

             </modal>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I know exactly what you mean. I don't think you could turn off isolated scope off globally in angular.

For a directive however, you would just not include the scope property in the object returned by your directive function.

Notice in your modal directive

```
scope: true
```

Remove this line. Typically scope would be an object that initializes a new isolated scope that only looks for what you have explicitly passed into it.

Comment: I tried removing the line as well as setting scope:false. still see the issue. problem is when i close the model popup , this is not applied until i load developer tools  and refresh the screen.                                               $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                            });
                        });

Comment: Hello Friends , I found the route cause and the issue is i am using resource and scope together and during rest calls, i see that it behaving not as expected. I created the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/xSJm5hpfSTz11EzlQGVf?p=preview , if any one can take a look and help me

Comment: Hello Friends , I found the route cause and the issue is i am using resource and scope together and during rest calls, i see that it behaving not as expected. I created the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/xSJm5hpfSTz11EzlQGVf?p=preview , if any one can take a look and help me